# Does a process inherits its Environment Variables from its parent or does it get them from Windows?

Tags: c, winapi, environment-variables

Each process in Windows has its own Environment Variables. But I am not sure how does a process gets its Environment Variables, does it get them from the "global Environment Variables" that Windows provides, I mean those Environment Variables:

[image]

Or does it inherit them from its parent process (and only the first parent process gets its Environment Variables from Windows)?

Comment: The `smss.exe` process ("windows session manager") has a very limited set of environment variables.  I'd *guess* that this is the only process started by the kernel, and that it is responsible for reading the stored system environment variables and passing them to other early-running processes (such as `csrss.exe` and `wininit.exe`).  User variables are probably read in by `userinit.exe` or perhaps `winlogon.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [Environment Variables (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx), a child process inherits all environment variables from its parent process. Additionally, a parent process may use [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to create a child process and pass a new set of environment variables to it.

Apart from that, programs that are started by the command processor (CMD) inherit the CMD environment variables, which are also listed in the screenshot you attached to your question.

Comment: So **cmd.exe** and **explorer.exe** both get their Environment Variables from the "global Environment Variables", and then when a process is launched from within **cmd.exe** or **explorer.exe**, the process will inherit these Environment Variables?

Comment: @John: AFAIK, the details aren't documented and are subject to change.  But it seems likely that when Explorer launches a process, it gives it a copy of the global environment variables.  `cmd.exe` doesn't seem to do anything special.

Comment: One correction: CreateProcess allows you to specify a different set of environment variables for the child process.  These aren't *extra* variables, they replace the current environment rather than being added to it.

Comment: You're right @HarryJohnston. I updated the answer to correct my misinformation. Thanks!